# React Router Dom child routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am creating a small react app where I have placed routes on the root component like this

```
return (
    <div>
        <Header />
        <Route exact path='/' component={Homepage}/>
        <Route exact path='/shop' component={Shop}/>
        <Route exact path='/shop/:category' component={Category}/>
    </div>
)
```

I want to place the `/shop/:category` route as a child route on the Shop component as below

```
render() {
    const {match} = this.props
        return (
            <div>
                <Route exact path={`${match.path}`} component={Collection}/>
                <Route exact path={`${match.path}/:category`} component={Category}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

When i do this the category component just won't render but it renders when i place the route on the App component it does render. I have logged the match object and it is fine because even the Collection page that is using the same is rendering but for whatever reason the second route just will not render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`exact` attribute makes a Route render ONLY if the current location path is the same as the provided `path`  attribute.

When your current location path is in `/shop/:category` it will not render `<Route exact path='/shop' component={Shop}/>` because `/shop/:category !== /shop`

Try removing `exact` attribute for component that has sub routes inside

```
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Route exact path='/' component={Homepage}/>
        <Route path='/shop' component={Shop}/>
      </div>
```